# How to catch form submit with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

When I test and click my `apply` button after I put in data in my input fields, I get a *file not found error*.

The `Login` button is a dummy button with no functionality to it. I want to only display an alert box that says **"You logged in as (user name here) Succesfully!!!"** after apply is clicked.

```
var Credentials = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#login-form"),

  events: {
    "click #login": "login"
  },

  initialize: function(){
    var self = this;

    this.firstname = $("#username");
    this.lastname = $("#lastname");
    this.number = $("#number");
    this.username = $("#username");
    this.password = $("#password");

    this.firstname.change(function(e){
      self.model.set({firstname: $(e.currentTarget).val()});
    });

    this.lastname.change(function(e){
      self.model.set({lastname: $(e.currentTarget).val()});
    });

    this.number.change(function(e){
      self.model.set({number: $(e.currentTarget).val()});
    });

    this.username.change(function(e){
      self.model.set({username: $(e.currentTarget).val()});
    });

    this.password.change(function(e){
      self.model.set({password: $(e.currentTarget).val()});
    });
  },

  login: function(){
    var firstn= this.model.get('firstname');
    var lastn= this.model.get('lastname');
    var numb= this.model.get('number');
    var user= this.model.get('username');
    var pword = this.model.get('password');

    alert("You logged in as " + user + "Succesfully!!!");

    return false;
  }
});

window.LoginView = new LoginView({model: new Credentials()});
});
```

---

```
<form action="/login" id="login-form" align="left">
    <h1> Your Registration Form:</h1>

    First Name <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
    Last Name <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
    Phone No. <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="1(555)555-5555">
    UserName <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="UserName">
    Password <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">

    <button id="login" onclick="">Apply</button>
    <!-- dummy button  -->
    <button id="login-button">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: While you have provided code, it should **demonstrate the problem** with the **shortest** code sample.

Comment: Also, [stack snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) are for on-site runnable code, if it can't, use a code sample (indent code to 4 spaces).

Comment: good tips and feedback Emile.

Comment: Ok, I see improvements, but it could be even shorter. We do not need the CSS, so that can be cut out completely. We do not need 5 input fields, in fact, the input fields (and the Backbone code managing their data) isn't needed at all. All the HTML boilerplate is also in the way, we only need the relevant HTML (`#login-form`) to answer.

Comment: Other improvements to your question: Put the question first, then the code sample, split the code by language if possible, _"Any suggestions? Cheers."_ just adds noise to your question and will be removed by edits, explain clearly what you're trying to achieve, what is happening instead, and steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: See the [advanced markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your question to its best. Wrap inline code with backticks so code inside a sentence stands out, like `this`.

Comment: If you have 2 code blocks that you want to split, you can just put text between them, or use a horizontal line (`---`).

Comment: very helpful thanks man.

Comment: any ideas why the alert doesn't come up after apply is clicked?

Comment: I wasn't going to answer your question at first, as there are too many poorly formatted questions to bother trying to figure out what each one wants. But you really have a great attitude towards criticism and you made the effort to improve your question. So it was a pleasure to help you. Welcome to SO and I hope you have fun learning and participating here.

Comment: You should use the event hash instead of `this.password.change(function(e){})`

Comment: @TJ There's an example and explanations in my answer about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Why a *file not found* error?

You get a file not found error because the form is submitted and the action is `"/login"` with the default method being a `GET` request, so the submit makes a `GET` request to the `login` page but it doesn't exist on the server. The server returns a `File not found` error.

## How to prevent the submit?

You need to stop the submit with JavaScript. To do that, first catch the submit event, then call `.preventDefault()` on the submit event object.

## How to catch the submit event with Backbone?

Backbone offers the [`events` property](http://backbonejs.org/#View-events) on views.

> The **events** hash (or method) can be used to specify a set of DOM events
>   that will be bound to methods on your View through [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).

The following is the simplest way of catching a `submit` event, granted the root element of the view is the form, like in your code.

```
events: {
    "submit": "onSubmit",
},

onSubmit: function(e) {
    // `e` being a standard DOM event
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Here I simplified your view:

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Put the string into a template to ease the manipulation later on.
    template: _.template("You logged in as <%= username %> and a password of <%= password %>\nFirstName:<%= firstname %>\nLastName:<%= lastname %>\nNumber:<%= number %>"),
    el: $("#login-form"),

    events: {
        // listen for the submit event of the form
        "submit": "onSubmit",
        // listen to events from here
        "change #username": 'onUsernameChange'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        // it's a good idea to cache jQuery objects like this.
        this.firstname = $("#username");
        this.lastname = $("#lastname");
        this.number = $("#number");
        this.username = $("#username");
        this.password = $("#password");

        // but avoid extensive `change` listeners as it's inefficient and
        // useless in this case. If you want to listen to changes, do it 
        // in the events hash, like the "onUsernameChange" example.
    },

    onSubmit: function(e) {
        // prevent the submit and do what you want instead
        e.preventDefault();

        // Set directly with an object, it's quick and clean.
        this.model.set({
            firstname: this.firstname.val(),
            lastname: this.lastname.val(),
            number: this.number.val(),
            username: this.username.val(),
            password: this.password.val()
        });

        // use the template for the alert.
        alert(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },

    onUsernameChange: function(e) {
        // no need for jQuery for a trivial value retrieval
        console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
    }
});
```

Specify the form buttons type attribute as it's `submit` by default. So making the `#login-button` a `type="button"` ensures it won't trigger a submit.

```
<button type="submit" id="login">Apply</button>

<!-- dummy button  -->
<button type="button" id="login-button">Login</button>
```

## Why isn't it working when using the exact code above?

Notice that the root element of the view is specified with the [`el` property](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el).

In your initial code, you're using [jQuery's core function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) to find and pass the form element to the view. But for it to work, **the form element must exist before running the JS** of the view.

So the HTML page structure should look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- head stuff like CSS, title, etc.  -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="login-form">
            <!-- rest of the form goes here -->
        </form>

        <!-- Load the scripts here -->
        <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/backbone/backbone.js"></script>

        <!-- then your own code can go here, or into another js file. -->
        <script>
            // your view, etc.
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You get a file not found error because the forms is submitted and **`the actions is "/login"`** so it tries to load the login page but it doesn't exist on the server.     ok now I understand the flaw of mis-using that action.

Comment: @AndreasLambadarios since we're catching the submit event, the form's `action` is now irrelevant. It could be anything, we're not using it. I was just explaining where the error comes from.

Comment: you're very clear and concise with everything you explain.

Comment: the alert box for some reason is not appearing on sumbit when i'm testing your answered code.

Comment: @andreas put the JavaScript after the html, just before closing the body

Comment: I put the javascript after my html and the input fields just clear on submit and no alert box appears.

Comment: the alert box still doesn't appear after I put my script before the body end tag

Comment: the way you re-did the markup made it clearer for me.  also the html page structure window helped visually.  thank you for spending a lot of time on this problem with me man.  +rep